# Image not rendered correctly in Angular

Tags: angular, image

Using the following line of code:

```
<img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/DOrhbkYbFkg">
```

I want to display a picture in my angular6 app.

However, all that is displayed is a tiny square with a question mark:

[image]

Why is the image not displayed?
Is there anything special about images in angular I am not aware of?

Comment: Try with `src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503624886539-b1355ee1a745?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=130627d9d7ebf62d9334702ecd0e5fa3"`.

Comment: The URL in the `src` property renders an HTML page, not an image. You need to make sure the URL leads directly to an image asset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That url is not the url of the image.  If you right click on the image and click on copy image url, you will get the proper url.